# Is there a way to enforce "Final" method from Traits?

Tags: php, final, traits

it seems that Final does not work from traits. is there a way to enforce final from traits?

No error in this code:

```
trait foo { final public function final_method() {} }

class bar
{
    use foo;
    public function final_method() {}
}

class baz extends bar
{
    public function final_method() {}
}

$baz = new baz(); // no errors
```

Comment: Why would you want to? Final is used to dictate inheritance behavior, but traits are designed to centralize logic among decoupled objects.

Comment: if for example the trait holds the magic method __get and i want the __get to return a private property from the current (parent) object and not the sub-class property with the same name.

Comment: Couldn't you just attach the trait to the parent, which should still be accessible by the child class, then make calls to `self::__get()`?